# django ajax request

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I am having a problem sending a form with Ajax. I have a form which i want to replace with another form asynchronously on clicking the next button.

Here is the script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#MY_FORM').submit(function() { 
        $.ajax({
            data: $(this).serialize(), 
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            url: $(this).attr('action'), 
            success: function(response) { 
                $('#FORM_DIV').html(response); 
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

form.py

```
class CountyForm(forms.Form):
    county = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=County.objects.all(),
              empty_label='---Select a county---', required=False)
    other = forms.CharField(required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CountyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.html5_required = True
        self.helper.form_id = 'MY_FORM'
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('next', 'Next', css_class='classfinish'))
        self.helper.layout = Layout('county','other')


class WardForm(forms.Form):
    ward = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Ward.objects.all(),
             empty_label='Select a ward')
    other = forms.CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(WardForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.html5_required = True
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('save', 'Finish'))
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('cancel', 'Cancel'))
        self.helper.layout = Layout('ward','other')
```

views

```
def location(request):
    if request.is_ajax() :
        wardform = WardForm()
        return HttpResponse(wardform)
    countyform = CountyForm()
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render(request,'location.html', {'countyform': countyform})
```

I want when i click next button in the county form, the ward form to appear.

Comment: What's your question? You're missing a quote after `#FORM_DIV` though.

Comment: Your JS has a syntax error

Comment: @Pavel was a typo, thanks.

Comment: @Blender would you please help debug it. am not good at it.

Comment: Open developer tools in whatever browser you are using, you should be able to get hold of javascript error. Here is details on how to find developer tools in different browsers - http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9225073/Essential_browser_tools_for_Web_developers

Comment: Also which version of django are you using , you will have to be careful about csrf middleware in django , https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/

Comment: it would be more suitable to create a view only for the ajax call since it will be hard to process the POST of thes two form in the same view. et will be far more readable too

Comment: This also seems as if you would like to upgrade to a formwizard instead of a two form part type solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

This could be solved in two ways, I won't cover FormWizard but I'll give you the link to the documentation which is really good.

My recommendation is that you should go for a FormWizard (depending on what version of Django you have) but I think it was migrated into Django at 1.2 and onwards but don't quote me on that.

In you current predicament you should do something along the lines of this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#MY_FORM').submit(function() { 
        $.ajax({
            data: $(this).serialize(), 
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            url: $(this).attr('action'), 
            success: function(response) { 
                $('#FORM_DIV').load('/some/url/to/a/wardform'); //new code 
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

views.py

```
def ward_form_renderer(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        ward_form = WardForm()
        #depending on version of django
        context = {'wardform': ward_form}
        context.update(csrf(request))
        render(request, 'wardform_template', c)
```

What this will do is that it will pull a new html page with a rendered form
from your Django view and display it. Basically what you've then done is a FormWizard.
This approach will have other side effects so I wouldn't recommend doing it this way.

I myself is in a project that does this and it's more pain than pleasure to be honest.
I haven't tried this code myself but you get the gist of how it should work.

Enter FormWizard! This is particular good choice for you since you dont have to redefine your forms, you can use the ones you have.

[Here's the link to the FormWizard docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/)

Good luck!